USA - Received Form 1042 S after filing taxes
I am an international student on F1 visa. I have been in the US for around 8 years. I kept some money in a CD during the beginning of 2023 and it matured in December' 23. I recently got the 1042S for it. But I've already filed my taxes and also the tax deadline is gone -
What are the next steps for me?
If I have to file an amended return, what's the cheapest option that's not too time-consuming? I filed my tax return by going to the VITA program hosted by my university.
Edit -
I understand that I am not a non-resident alien anymore. For some reason, my bank sent me a 1042 S instead of W2. Not to mention, they sent it quite late. I cannot ask VITA (free tax program by IRS partners) to redo it, as the program has been closed for the year.

Did you tell the bank your status changed? For a (known) tax-resident they would send 1099-INT, not W-2 which is only from your employer. Some VITA sites close after April 15, but some remain open longer -- if you find one in your area using the IRS website, and if you gave the first site permission to save your data (as is recommended if you expect to come back next year), I'm pretty sure that data will be available (with your authorization of course) to the other site because they all use the same IRS-supplied network software.

Thank you for your comment. Do you suggest, I call my bank and let them know? Should I then ask them to send a 1099-NT?
Thank you for your idea regarding open VITA offices. There's one but it's 80 miles from my home. I'd rather not make that trip.

Call them, look on the website, walk into a branch (if they still have branches and you still have legs), whatever. With filing season officially over you probably can't to get them to change the reporting for last year, but if you give them your updated info they should use it when reporting this year next Jan, and future years. (Like most resident info returns -- 1099, 1098, and a few others -- they are supposed to send or provide your copy of 1099-INT by Jan. 31, not the March 15 plus 30-day extension for 1042-S.)

Yes, you need to amend your tax return.

If I have to file an amended return, what's the cheapest option that's not too time-consuming? I filed my tax return by going to the VITA program hosted by my university.

Can't they also do the amended return for you? You can also do it yourself, it's not that complicated.

You've been on F1 for 8 years. Why do you think you're considered non-resident? You would by now be passing the substantial presence test since the F1 status is only excluded for 5 calendar years.

Thank you for the reply. I have updated my question with the answers to your questions.
I think I'll do the tax amendment myself. Should I file a 1040 X?
